# First date of a week

Tags: php

I want a First Day Of a week say I have 45th week. Now I want to have date of the first sunday of this week. 
 Can any one suggest me how I can go about this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching around a bit, the most suggested is:

```
$year = "2009"; // date("Y");
$week = "45"; // date("W");

$firstDayOfWeek = strtotime($year."W".str_pad($week,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT));

print("The first day of week ".$week." of ".$year." is ".date("D, d-m-Y",$firstDayOfWeek));
```

Basically this comes down to letting **strtotime** do the work for you. You fill in "2009W45" and it'll retrieve the date for you.
Pitfall here is that the week needs to be in a 2 digit format. So week 1 needs to be 01, hence the str_pad to zero-fill it.

Answer (score 1):

you should [strtotime](http://fr.php.net/strtotime) and [date](http://fr.php.net/date) function

some code like that

```
$next_sunday = strtotime('next sunday');
$next_week = strtotime('+1 week');
$next_sunday_of_next_week = strtotime('next sunday', $next_week);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have the month, day and year:

```
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
 echo date('c', $timestamp) = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, date('d', $timestamp)-date('w', $timestamp), $year);
```

you could also do it this way if you have the timestamp:

```
echo $date('c', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, date('d', $timestamp)-date('w', $timestamp), $year));
```

From: http://pinoytech.org/blog/post/get-the-first-day-of-the-week-with-an-exact-date

Answer (score 0):

`date($str_format, strtotime($year."W".$week."1"))`

Where `$str_format` is the output formate according to the PHP `date()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).. I use `'M d Y'`