# strtotime for weekdays starting on actual week

Tags: php, date, weekday

I'm trying to get the starting monday date of the actual week we are in. Like we are July 15th and would like to have the result with strtotime to return July 11th...

I've tried

```
strtotime("-1 weekdays");
```

Without luck... What could be the function for the actual week please.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923925/get-start-and-end-days-for-a-given-week-in-php

Comment: The anwser below is much clearer and accurate than the one in your link. My opinion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$timestamp = strotime('monday this week');`

Will give you Monday! ;)

Comment: @Warface great! Now, in Stack Overflow style (SO) you should accept the answer if you think it helped you. That way you'll improve my reputation and you'll also get some points for yourself. You probably should spend 3 minutes reading the FAQ to familiarize yourself with the community. http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Yeah I had to wait 10 minutes before accepting your anwser. Sorry for the delay but it's Stack Overflow fault :D

Comment: @Warface, hehe... sorry! Just saw that you were a new member and threw you the guidelines! ;) Thks!

Answer (score 0):

Did none of these help you to find your answer?

- [Get first day of week in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)
- [Finding First day of week via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439722/finding-first-day-of-week-via-php)
- [First date of a week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685714/first-date-of-a-week)