# Get first week date of the month providing day?

Tags: php, date

Is there any PHP function that returns the date of the first week ,

i:e, if i pass "Monday" , it should return 02 of september,
i know, how to get the day, month, date like

```
date('l') , date('m'), date ('d')
```

But stuck at this point

Comment: possible duplicate of [First date of a week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685714/first-date-of-a-week)

Comment: You don't need to call date 3 times `date('l, m, d')` would suffice

Comment: But, those were only example,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
$dt = new DateTime('first Monday of this month');
echo $dt->format('l m d');
```

**[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/50UOa)**

Comment: This Works great!

But the people mentioned a reference at the top did'nt work at all for my situation,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Your code works for me, but someone post "

This question may already have an answer here:

    First date of a week 6 answers

" was not according to my situation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime), like so:

```
function getDateFromDay($day) {
    return date('d-m-Y', strtotime("first $day of this month"));
}
```

Usage:

```
echo getDateFromDay('Monday');
```

Output:

```
02-09-2013
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/49094)